# python design patterns

Tags: python, design-patterns

I am looking for any resources that gives examples of Best Practices, Design patterns and the SOLID principles using Python.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/127377/programming-languages-and-design-patterns, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/546479/do-oo-design-principles-apply-to-python, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/112358/what-are-some-good-web-resources-for-learning-object-oriented-programming

Comment: https://github.com/faif/python-patterns/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 153, accepted):

Some overlap in these

[Intermediate and Advanced Software Carpentry in Python](https://web.archive.org/web/20180504173504/http://ivory.idyll.org/articles/advanced-swc/)

[Code Like a Pythonista: Idiomatic Python](https://web.archive.org/web/20180411011411/http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html)

[Python Idioms and Efficiency](https://web.archive.org/web/20120118192448/http://jaynes.colorado.edu/PythonIdioms.html)

[Google Developers Day US - Python Design Patterns](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0vJJlVBVTFg)

Another resource is by example at the [Python Recipes](https://github.com/ActiveState/code).  A good number do not follow best practices but you can find some patterns in there that are useful

Comment: The third link is dead. Tried to find mirror but couldn't, If anybody has the correct link please add

Comment: Same here, _Python Idioms and Efficiency_ doesn't seem to work.

Comment: The first and second links were dead so I updated them with Internet Archive snapshots. They seem to be very old though, although I'm sure a lot of it is still relevant.

Answer (score 25):

Type

```
>>> import this
```

in a Python console.

Although this is usually treated as a (fine!) joke, it contains a couple of valid python-specific axioms.

Answer (score 13):

Bruce Eckel's *[Thinking in Python](http://docs.linuxtone.org/ebooks/Python/Thinking_In_Python.pdf)* leans heavily on Design Patterns

Comment: Note that according to the [wiki](http://wiki.python.org/moin/AdvancedBooks) this book is no longer maintained.

Comment: updated link [thinking in python] (http://www.mindview.net/Books/Python/ThinkingInPython.html)

Answer (score 6):

You can get started [here](http://www.python.org/workshops/1997-10/proceedings/savikko.html) and [here](http://www.suttoncourtenay.org.uk/duncan/accu/pythonpatterns.html).

For a more in depth look at design pattners you should look at [Design Patterns: Elements of Reusable Object-Oriented Software](http://www.amazon.ca/Design-Patterns-Elements-Reusable-Object-Oriented/dp/0201633612).  The source code is not in Python, but it doesn't need to be for you to understand the patterns.

Comment: I think that it is important to understand how to use idiomatic python for implementing design patterns. It is a very different language than C++ which is used in GOF thus porting from C++ to python will result in non-pythonic code.

Comment: I tend to disagree. A singleton DP or other DP's will be possible in any OO language, whether it be Python, Java, or C++. What is non-pythonic in your opinion?

Comment: The first link is a fairly poor paper, with many mistaken assertions about Python. The second currently 404's, thus, I suppose, doing far less damage :)

Answer (score 6):

Something you can use to simplify your code when calling attributes on objects that might or might not exist is to use the [Null Object Design Pattern](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/68205-null-object-design-pattern/) (to which I was introduced in [Python Cookbook](http://books.google.com.ar/books?id=Q0s6Vgb98CQC&pg=PT311&lpg=PT311&dq=Null+object+python+cookbook&source=bl&ots=hc3368UkpC&sig=qRrDqvZwg4FIoMuKo3JJhI7Bu_g&hl=es&ei=TiqpS5jZEMuVtgf08YGnAQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=4&ved=0CBYQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=&f=false)).

> Roughly, the goal with Null objects is to provide an 'intelligent'
>   replacement for the often used primitive data type None in Python or
>   Null (or Null pointers) in other languages. These are used for many
>   purposes including the important case where one member of some group 
>   of otherwise similar elements is special for whatever reason. Most 
>   often this results in conditional statements to distinguish between
>   ordinary elements and the primitive Null value.

This object just eats the lack of attribute error, and you can avoid checking for their existence.

It's nothing more than

```
class Null(object):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        "Ignore parameters."
        return None

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        "Ignore method calls."
        return self

    def __getattr__(self, mname):
        "Ignore attribute requests."
        return self

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        "Ignore attribute setting."
        return self

    def __delattr__(self, name):
        "Ignore deleting attributes."
        return self

    def __repr__(self):
        "Return a string representation."
        return "<Null>"

    def __str__(self):
        "Convert to a string and return it."
        return "Null"
```

With this, if you do `Null("any", "params", "you", "want").attribute_that_doesnt_exists()` it won't explode, but just silently become the equivalent of `pass`.

Normally you'd do something like

```
if obj.attr:
    obj.attr()
```

With this, you just do:

```
obj.attr()
```

and forget about it. Beware that extensive use of the `Null` object can potentially hide bugs in your code.

Answer (score 3):

You may also wish to read this [article](http://people.csail.mit.edu/gregs/ref-dyn-patterns.html) (select the .pdf file), which discusses Design Patterns in dynamic object oriented languages (i.e. Python). To quote the page:

> This paper explores how the patterns from the "Gang of Four", or "GOF" book, as it is often called, appear when similar problems are addressed using a dynamic, higher-order, object-oriented programming language. Some of the patterns disappear -- that is, they are supported directly by language features, some patterns are simpler or have a different focus, and some are essentially unchanged.

Comment: The question was about Python; the paper talks about Scheme-like language that is, from what I can tell, invented on-the-spot for this particular paper. Unless the questioner is (a) an academic computer scientist with (b) long experience with Python practices, I doubt if they could get anything of value out of the paper — and, more to the point, they would probably not have asked this question in the first place. :)