# Python Observer Design Pattern

Tags: python, design-patterns

I have two questions:

1. I'm trying to implement an Observer design pattern in Python. What is the easiest implementation for that?

   I need it to observe the status of machines in a render farm that I'm currently building.
2. Are there any good Python design pattern books out there?

Comment: Your question says "Observer" the title says "State".  Please pick one design pattern for both question and title.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1904351/python-observer-pattern-examples-tips

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are already some nice sources of information about [design patterns in Python](http://www.python.org/workshops/1997-10/proceedings/savikko.html).

[Here's an interesting book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0130409561) on Python design patterns.

Last but not least...Alex Martelli gave a [very interesting talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0vJJlVBVTFg) regarding this issue for Google Developer Day US.

**Edit:**
After reading that this is a duplicate of [another StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/606448/python-design-patterns), I would recommend that everyone read that one as well. There are a lot of useful links and comments there.

Answer (score 2):

You can find a discussion on python design patterns in this previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/606448/python-design-patterns).

An implementation of an observer pattern is given [here](http://www.suttoncourtenay.org.uk/duncan/accu/pythonpatterns.html#observer).

Answer (score 0):

Examples of Python implementations of the observer design pattern can be found in the following books:

- Data formatter: "Every time the value of the default formatter is updated, the registered formatters are notified and take action." [Mastering Python Design Patterns, section "The Observer Pattern" subsection "Implementation" / Kindle pos. 2416]
- "(... ) Every observer gets a Unit timestamp an will print it out in either the USA (12 hour) format or the (24 hour) EU format." [Learning Python Design Patterns, section "Observer design pattern" subsection "Implementation in Python" /Kindle pos. 900]

Kasampalis, Sakis | Mastering Python Design Patterns | Packt Publishing Ltd. | 1st | 2015

Zlobin, Gennadiy | Learning Python Design Patterns | Packt Publishing Ltd. | 1st | 2013

By the way: A lot of other references to design pattern implementation examples in Python can be found on [eswp3.org](http://eswp3.org).