# Design patterns for working with text

Tags: design-patterns, text

I'm working on a rich text editor and I would like to study some design patterns for working with text.  I know there are lots of editors out there ago I assume some good patterns exist.  However, I'm having trouble finding good resources.

Are there any good books on this topic?
What about open source projects with good code that is easy to read?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you could have a look at the must-read design patterns book, "Design patterns : elements of reusable object-oriented software" by GoF.

They have an example there based on a text editor in the beginning, before presenting every pattern in detail.

Better patterns may exists for today, but that is a very good starting point on top of which you might optimize or at least gain an idea on where to head to.

Answer (score 0):

If you are a Python programmer you can check the following design patterns resources, they are easy to follow and applied every where.
 www.youtube.com/watch?v=0vJJlVBVTFg 
http://www.aleax.it/gdd_pydp.pdf
[python design patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/606448/python-design-patterns).

Understanding will definitely help you out.