# Working with trees of class instances in Python

Tags: python, class-hierarchy

I'm looking for more information about dealing with trees of class instances, and how best to go about calling methods on the leaves from the trunk. I have a trunk instance with many branch instances (in a dictionary), and each has many leaf instances (and dicts in the branches). The leaves are where the action really happens, and as such there are methods in the leaves for querying values, restoring values, and many other things.

This leads to what feels like duplication of code, as I might want to do something to all leaves of a branch, so there are methods in the branches for doing something to a leaf, a specified set of leaves, or all leaves known to that branch, though these do reduce the code duplication by simply looping over the leafs and asking them to do said things to themselves (thus the actual code doing the work is in one place in the leaf class).

Then the trunk comes in, where I might want to do something to the entire tree (i.e. all leaves) in one fell swoop, so I have methods there that ask all known objects to run their all-leaf functions. I start to feel pretty removed from the real action in the leaves this way, though it works fine, and the code seems fairly tight - extremely brief, readable, and functioning fine.

Another issue comes in logical groupings. There are bits of data I might want to associate with some, most, or all leaves, to indicate that they're part of some logical group, so currently the leaves themselves are all storing that kind of data. When I want to get a logical group, I have to scan all leaves and gather them back up, rather than having some sort of list at the trunk level. This actually all works fine, and is even pretty logical, yet it feels insane. Is this simply the nature of working with tree-like structures, because of their complexity, or are there other ways of doing these kinds of things? I prefer not to build secondary structures to connect to things from the opposite direction - e.g. making a structure with references to the leaves in a logical group, approaching them then from that more list-like direction. One bonus of keeping things all in a large tree like this is that it can be dumped and loaded in one shot with pickle.

I'd love to hear thoughts - any and all - from anyone else's experience with such things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I'm taking away from your question is that "everything works", but that the code is starting to feel unmanagable and difficult to reason about, and: is there a better way to do this?

The one thing your question is missing is a solid context. What sort of problem is your tree structure actually solving?  What do these object actually do? Are they all the same type of object, or is there a mix of objects? With some of these specifics you might get more practical responses.

As it stands, I would suggest checking out some resources on [design patterns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_pattern_%28computer_science%29). Specifically the [composite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern) and [visitor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) patterns.

On the book end of things you could have a look at [Design Patterns](http://www.amazon.ca/Design-Patterns-Elements-Reusable-Object-Oriented/dp/0201633612/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1316587118&sr=8-1) and/or [Refactoring to Patterns](http://www.amazon.ca/Design-Patterns-Elements-Reusable-Object-Oriented/dp/0201633612/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1316587118&sr=8-1). Neither of these have any Python code in them, but if you don't mind Java, the latter is an excellent introduction to taking hard to reason code structures and using a pattern to better organize things.

You might also have a look at Alex Martelli's talk on [Python Design Patterns](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0vJJlVBVTFg).

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/606448/python-design-patterns) has some further resource links regarding patterns and python in general.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, Mark. You're basically right about my vague line of questioning. You're also not the first to recommend design patterns to me. I think I'm finally ready to take the hint. I'm currently searching out a copy of the Design Patterns book.